# Can't get associations to work using sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a web app which performs database operations like create select etc. using node.js with express and sequelize. I can't get the associactions to work tho, it seems to work in index.js but when I'm trying to display the values in index.jade it doesn't, and now for some reason the page refuses to even load after I press the button to add the author to the book. Here's my code:
index.js:

```
var authors = [];
var books = [];

//SEQUELIZE
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
sequelize = new Sequelize('main', '', '', {
  dialect : "sqlite",//,
  port : 3306
}) 

var Author = sequelize.define('author', {
name: { 
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    isAlpha: true
},
age: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    isNumeric: true,
    allowNull: true
}

})

var Book = sequelize.define('book', {
name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
pages: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
}

})

Author.hasMany(Book, {joinTableName: 'authors_books_bridge'});
Book.hasMany(Author, {joinTableName: 'authors_books_bridge'});

Author.belongsToMany(Book);
Book.belongsToMany(Author);

function saveAuthor(m){
Author
  .create(m)
    .complete(function(err, m) {
        if (!!err){
            console.log('not saved')
        }
        authors.push(m);
        console.log('saved')
    })
}

function saveBook(m){
Book
  .create(m)
    .complete(function(err, m) {
        if (!!err){
            console.log('not saved')
        }
        books.push(m);
        console.log('saved')
    })
}

sequelize.sync({force: true});
//SEQUELIZE

//ROUTERS
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index',{authors: authors,books: books});
});

router.post("/", function(req, res) {
    var createdItem = req.body;
    var selectedBook = createdItem.book;
    var selectedAuthor = createdItem.author;

    var resBook = books.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.name == selectedBook;
    });
    var resAuthor = authors.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.name == selectedAuthor;
    });

    var foundAuthor;
    var foundBook;

    Author
        .find({where: {name: selectedAuthor}})
        .then(function(result) {
            foundAuthor = result;//here the variable foundAuthor is undefined outside the function, even if the variable is declared outside the function and is associated inside, why?
            console.log("Found author");
            Book
                .find({where: {name: selectedBook}})
                .then(function(result) {
                    foundBook = result;
                    foundBook.addAuthor(foundAuthor);
                    books[foundBook.dataValues.id - 1] = foundBook;
                    console.log("Found book");
                })
        })

    res.render('index',{authors: authors,books: books});
```

index.jade:

```
div
    table
        thead
            tr
                th Name
                th Authors
        tbody
        - if(books != undefined)
            - for(index = 0, len = books.length; index < len; index++)
                tr
                    td= books[index].name
                    - books[index].getAuthors().success(function(auth){
                        - for (i=0;len = auth.length;i++){
                            - if(auth[i] != undefined)
                                td= auth[i].dataValues.name
                        -}
                    -});
```

I've been trying to make this work the whole day. Thanks

Comment: In your post request, you're rendering the page before waiting the answer of the bdd (async coding) + `authors` and `books` aren't defined (checkout your stacktrace in your console)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. authors and books are declared on top, and I have another form and fill them with objects using the saveAuthor and saveBook functions(see sequelize part), so assume they have items inside. The page now loads after removing the last for loop in index.jade... still can't make it show the authors

Comment: Avoid logic in your template (and moreover promise based methods - jade may not manage them well) - populate `books[index].authors` via `books[index].getAuthors().suc ...` in your controller

Comment: Thanks. Ok I got it to work and show the authors, but only after I press the button twice...any idea why?  I added this after foundBook.addAuthor(foundAuthor):  foundBook.getAuthors().success(function(auth){books[foundBook.dataValues.id - 1].authors = auth;});

Comment: If you could update your code sample, because from what I see, on your post request, you first try to find the posted author, then in the success, find his books.
What if this author doesn't exist ? you should have error callbacks + render the page only when you found them (not sequencially)

Comment: Thanks. I made it work by adding the code in my last comment on foundBook.addAuthor(foundAuthor).success(....  It will pretty much find the selected items always except if there are no items in the list, because the list gets populated automatically when I add items. I will try to add error callbacks now. Thanks a lot!